# JQuery. val() function not returning the input field value

Tags: jquery

The html code snipped is

```
<tr>
    <td>Wi-Fi Access Cards</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adj_accname_n" id="adj_accname_Id1" value="Electronic Recharge for Nawras Ajel"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" id="adj_acccode_Id1" value="420650"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" id="adj_prodname_Id1" value="Electronic Recharge for Nawras Ajel"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" id="adj_prodcode_Id1" value="240010"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" id="adj_channelcode_Id1" value="710300"></td>
    <!--<td><input type="submit" name="adj_button_n" id="adj_button_Id1" value="Modify"></td>-->
    <td><button>Modify</button></td>
</tr>
```

The above code snippet has one modify button for each row.  Likewise there are many rows each with the modify button.

When the user click on the modify button, all the values in the input field of that row should be retrieved.

The below code retrieves the html properly

```
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().siblings().eq(1).html());
});
```

But when I replace the html() with val() it returns blank where I as expecting the value from the input field

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings().eq(1).find('input').val()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find('input')` to get input field inside first `td`, `val()` works with `input` not with `td`

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().siblings().eq(1).find('input').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Wi-Fi Access Cards</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_accname_n" id="adj_accname_Id1" value="Electronic Recharge for Nawras Ajel">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" id="adj_acccode_Id1" value="420650">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" id="adj_prodname_Id1" value="Electronic Recharge for Nawras Ajel">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" id="adj_prodcode_Id1" value="240010">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" id="adj_channelcode_Id1" value="710300">
    </td>
    <!--<td><input type="submit" name="adj_button_n" id="adj_button_Id1" value="Modify"></td>-->
    <td>
      <button>Modify</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wi-Fi Access Cards</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_accname_n" id="adj_accname_Id1" value="Electronic Recharge for Nawras Ajel">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" id="adj_acccode_Id1" value="420650">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" id="adj_prodname_Id1" value="Electronic Recharge for Nawras Ajel">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" id="adj_prodcode_Id1" value="240010">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" id="adj_channelcode_Id1" value="710300">
    </td>
    <!--<td><input type="submit" name="adj_button_n" id="adj_button_Id1" value="Modify"></td>-->
    <td>
      <button>Modify</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @user1882395 : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

***When the user click on the modify button, all the values in the input field of that row should be retrieved.***

You can use:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   alert($(this).parent().siblings().find('input').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access all the input values in a row, on button click, you could use,

```
    $($(this).closest("tr").find("input")).each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Using the code,

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input").val()); //or
    alert($(this).parent().siblings().eq(1).val());
});
```

you could access a single input value on the click event.
In the case of

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("input").val();
```

the input value from the from the first cell of row is returned.

In the case of

```
$(this).parent().siblings().eq(1).val()
```

the input value from the second cell of row is returned, as position is mentioned.

As there are more than one `<td>` elements consisting of input elements, you should use `$.each()` function, in order to loop through all elements belonging to the category specified.

```
$($(this).closest("tr").find("input"))
```

specifies to access the `<tr>` element closest to the button element, which is the row consisting of the button element, and then to find all the elements in the resultant row.

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation.